# Is there a way to tell the differences of a PostgreSQL, MySQL or MSSQL connection resource?

Tags: php, database, connection, resource-id

If I have $dbConn (a database connection) and I don't know if it's MySQL, MSSQL or PostgreSQL can I tell what type of connection it is?

Just wanted to know if there is a method to return the connection type of a resource id?

EDIT: Sorry, yes PHP added the tag

Comment: I can assume `PHP` I think, but which database layer are you talking about?

Comment: Yes PHP (sry), Just wanted to see if there was a way (other than knowing) to test if a connection is to a MySQL, MSSQL or PostgreSQL database. It's just a thought I had and wanted to get some feedback

Comment: `var_dump` on the handle may identify its type, especially if the handle's an object and not just a simple int pointer into an internal table somewhere.

Comment: what do you mean by, say, a "connection to MySQL"? A result of `mysql_connect`, a result of `odbc_connect('mysql')`, an instance of `PDO('mysql')` or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$connection = mysql_connect(...); 

$is_mysql = (get_resource_type($connection) == 'mysql link');
$is_ibase = (get_resource_type($connection) == 'Firebird/InterBase link'); // *

var_dump($is_mysql); // -> true

// * supposed to be "interbase link" but isn't any longer
```